# Gesture Recognition In Android

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gestures

I'm new to Android and I'm working on `Gestures`. I have a problem regarding how to recognise the text. When a user draws a letter or number that has to be recognised and has to be printed on the top of the screen. I came to know that it can be done through `GestureOverlayView`but dont know how to implement it.

Can anyone please help me with some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can these two links which will be helpful

[GestureOverlay](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html)

[GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html)

Use this

```
public class YourClass extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {  
  private GestureLibrary mLibrary;   
mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);  
 if (!mLibrary.load()) {     
    finish();   
  }     
 GestureOverlayView gestures =    (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
     gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);  
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {  
   ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture); 
    Log.v("performed","performed");  
   // We want at least one prediction  
   if (predictions.size() > 0) {    
     Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);   
      // We want at least some confidence in the result   
      if (prediction.score > 1.0) {        
                 if(prediction.name.equalsIgnorecase("right")){    
                       //do you thing here//       
                }
```